# CocoaLibSpotify waitUntilLoaded rarely returns loaded items

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I've been building an ios app using `cocoalibspotify` for some time without any problems, but since yesterday both of my apps don't get any loaded data when calling the `waitUntilLoaded` method.

Here is a code example of how I call it:

```
[[SPSession sharedSession] trackForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Url] callback:^(SPTrack *track)
 {
     if (track != nil)
     {
         [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *tracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks)
         {
                 //code
         }];
     }
 }];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is working one day and not the next, its 's pretty clear that this is a backend problem. Indeed, the Spotify metadata service has been acting up these past couple of days. It should clear up soon.